# Having problems with Mailchimp API Editing Member of a list

Tags: php, mailchimp

Its not working for some odd reason.
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/update-member.php

I want to update the Notes section on a member.

Its acting like it posts fine.
returning a valid response no error code.
but its not adding a new note to the member.

```
$results = $MailChimp->call("lists/update-member",
            array(
                "id"=> "xxxxxxx", 
                "email" => array( 
                            "email" => "someemail@gmail.com",
                            "euid" => "xxxxxxx"
                            ),

                "merge_vars" => array(
                            "mc_notes" => array(
                                            "note" => "THIS IS MY NEW NOTE" 
                                        )
                            ),

                "update_existing"=> true,

            ));
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: And the response that are you getting??

Comment: no error messages. i updated my question.

Comment: Define "valid response", or post this output pls

Comment: array(3) { ["email"]=> string(22) "xxxxx@gmail.com" ["euid"]=> string(10) "xxxxx" ["leid"]=> string(8) "xxxxx" }

Comment: Can you check if the mc_notes get updated with null or empty values

Comment: It's not being updated at all. the notes field is empty when i log into mailchimp and check.

Comment: But try insert one note...and update the field, then check again

Comment: No, its not updating the notes. it returns an array with the information about the member, which the documentation shows as being a valid response from their server, but no notes are added, if i add a note to the member in the mail chimp user area, then use the API to output the info for the user, it shows the note, when i try to add another note with the API, it gives me the valid response again, but the note is not added.

Comment: adding, and updating using 'action' => 'replace' is also not working.